# Cannot add values to table using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to add new post to the table events. I'm confused because I have used this code in other place on the same website (but it was using mysqli_query to register new user). mysqql_error returns "No database selected"

This is the code:

```
<?php
$add_title = $_POST['add_title'];
$add_happen = $_POST['add_happen'];
$add_created = date('Y-m-d');
$add_content = $_POST['add_content'];
$add_author = $_POST['add_author'];

//connect to 
    //localhost
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_dbname = "zhp2";
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname); 

$query = "
    INSERT INTO events ( title, happen, created, content, author ) 
    VALUES ( '$add_title', '$add_happen', '$add_created', '$add_content', '$add_author') )
";

$retval = mysql_query($query,  $db_con);
if(! $retval ){
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
}

mysql_close($db_con);

//header('Location: ../../index.php?link=events');?>
```

I've tried to fix it using trial and error method playing with different combinations both mysql_query and mysqli_query

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).[This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide. [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: you have an extra ) at the end of your $query statement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_connect` functions in the way you pass those parameters. In your example:

```
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname);
```

you are passing a fourth parameter which is the database name but that wont work as you should only pass the three first (host,username,password) and then call `mysql_select_db()`:

```
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);   
mysql_select_db( $db_dbname, $db_con );
```

In `mysqli` which is the **BETTER** way of doing it since `mysql_` functions are very vulnerable and being deprecated from `php` you could pass four elements like here:

```
$db_con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username, $db_password, $db_dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

which is close to what you are trying to do, but in a correct `mysqli_` way.

Answer (score 4):

Well then, you need to select the database! ;) The fourth parameter of `mysql_connect()` is not the database name. You need to do this separate of connecting to the MySQL server.

Using `mysql_select_db()` function:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_dbname = "zhp2";
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password );
mysql_select_db( $db_dbname, $db_con );
```

***And of course all the obligatory warnings about [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), sanitizing your data, [deprecation of `mysql_*` functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).***

Answer (score 0):

You need to select which database to connect to using the `mysql_select_db` function:

```
// make $db_dbname the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($db_dbname, $db_con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can't use $db_dbname : " . mysql_error());
}
```

See the PHP manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php